# Can I disable an option when I call Intent.ACTION_VIEW?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, actionview

I am doing an application, and I have an Intent Filter in my manifest, this Intent Filter has the action

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```

and the categories

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

and, when I want to start a web page that contains the data declared in that intent filter, my app appear in the dialog, with the browser.

This is what I want, but there are a case when, when I press a specific button, i don't want to start my app, but it appears in the dialog.

Can I disable it?

PS. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I disable it?

Only by creating your own chooser dialog, using `PackageManager` and stuff like `queryIntentActivities()` to find out the possibilities, filter yourself out of that list, and build a dialog with the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can go like this, it's working perfectly fine.

```
void showBrowsers() {
    List<Intent> shareIntentsLists = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfos = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(browserIntent, 0);
    if (!resInfos.isEmpty()) {
        for (ResolveInfo resInfo : resInfos) {
            String packageName = resInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            if (!packageName.toLowerCase().contains("YOURPACKAGE_NAME")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, resInfo.activityInfo.name));
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                intent.setPackage(packageName);
                shareIntentsLists.add(intent);
            }
        }
        if (!shareIntentsLists.isEmpty()) {
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntentsLists.remove(0), "Choose Browser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, shareIntentsLists.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
            startActivity(chooserIntent);
        } else
            Log.e("Error", "No Apps can perform your task");
    }
}
```